# how can i add title , four author with affiliation in the same line and running head

Tags: titles, article

How can I add title , four author with affiliation in the same line and running head, all  together in the top pages, then next pages I need to add again title, abstract and keyword..., section...

my programm:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{authblk}%{for author}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{txfonts}
%\usepackage{graphicx} %{graphicx} in order to load pictures
%\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
%\usepackage{epstopdf} % to convert eps to pdf
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{natbib} 
%\usepackage{harvard} 
%\bibliographystyle{ifac}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\textwidth=16cm
\oddsidemargin=0cm
\textheight=24cm
\topmargin=-1.5cm
%
\newcommand{\sbf}[1]{%
\mbox{\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{b}\selectfont #1}}
\newcommand{\vb}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath $#1$}}
%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\emptythanks}{%
\renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\@thanks}{}}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
\title{Bar instability with bank erosion by \\
perturbation analysis from the case with no bank erosion}
%
\date{}

\author[1]{Md }
\author[2]{No}
\author[3]{K}
\author[4]{Ya}
\affil[1]{ Student \\
       Email:ooo@gmail.com}
\affil[2]{Pro \\
       Email:oo@eng.ya.cc}
\affil[3]{Dyyy}
\affil[4]{Doos}
\renewcommand\Authands{ and }
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
%\title{Title}
%\date{  }
\emptythanks

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
ooooooooooooooo

\end{abstract}
\section

uyrn opp,l

\end{document}
```

[image: 1st title page]

[image: 2nd title page]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: How can i solve.  Pls help me.

Comment: I'm afraid that a major issue, for me at least, is that I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. It would certainly be helpful if you provided more (and clearer!) information about the layout you're looking to get.

Comment: My question is: How can I add title + multiple author with affiliation in the same line + running head in the first title page, and then next title page I need to add title (no author) + abstract + keyword.  @Mico

Comment: Will the title and all authors (including their affiliations!) fit on a single line? If not, how is the information supposed to be split across lines? It would be helpful if you provided a realistic example rather than `Md `, `No`, etc.

Comment: pls see the added image    @Mico

Comment: There are places where using methods like `titling` or `authblk` aren't comfortable anymore and one has to do it all by hand. So i suggest to close this as a duplicate.